# Regular expression for link sting, php

Tags: php, preg-match

I trying to do regular expression for string like:

```
/Foteliai-Svetaines-baldai/kaina/internetu/1947?pg=1&rodPo=36&rusiuoti=bv
```

I try this:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9+]./kaina/internetu/.[\d+]+$/', '/Foteliai-Svetaines-baldai/kaina/internetu/1947?pg=1&rodPo=36&rusiuoti=bv')){
die('ok');
}
```

but is does not work, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to extract? For starters, you can't use the regex delimiter `/` inside the regular expression without escaping it.

Comment: I trying to check, are string is like at first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `\/[\w-]*\/kaina\/internetu\/\d*` will match the string.

If you wanted to catch the `Foteliai-Svetaines-baldai` or `1947` part of the string use:

`\/([\w-]*)\/kaina\/internetu\/(\d*)`

Using `preg_match` you'll get an array (if you choose to look at those values) of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /Foteliai-Svetaines-baldai/kaina/internetu/1947
    [1] => Foteliai-Svetaines-baldai
    [2] => 1947
)
```

Otherwise `preg_match` will just return `1` on success and your `die('ok')` will be executed.